# FFMpeg converts locally but not on Ubuntu production server

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ffmpeg & this command to convert a .mov to .mp4. It works locally but it will not work on the production server.

```
 Command: /path/to/ffmpeg inputFile.MOV -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slow -crf 22 -movflags +faststart outputFile.mp4
```

I have checked to see that ffmpeg is installed on the Ubuntu 14.04.x prod server...

```
 /usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

I get this error each time:

```
libavutil      55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
libavcodec     57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
libavformat    57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavfilter     6. 21.101 /  6. 21.101
libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Output #0, mov, to 'inputFile.MOV':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Per http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Segment-format-is-not-working-Output-file-0-does-not-contain-any-stream-td4535688.html, have you tried the -map 0 argument?

Comment: Yes, I've tried this "-vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slow -crf 22 -movflags +faststart -map 0". Is that the correct place to put that argument?

Comment: `ffmpeg` behavior differs a lot by build options and versions. You should add results of `ffmpeg` without arguments at local and at server both side.

Comment: -f mp4 -strict -2   try w/ those flags

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I forgot to add -i after ffmpeg in my Ubuntu command line script.

```
Command should b: /path/to/ffmpeg -i inputFile.MOV -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slow -crf 22 -movflags +faststart outputFile.mp4
```